# Where Elasticsearch grok patterns are defined?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, filebeat, syslog, grok

Good day every body

Where are Elasticsearch grok patterns defined?

in particular Syslog related items like  `SYSLOG5424PRI` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the patterns used by the `grok` processor of the ingest pipelines in elasticsearch [here in github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/libs/grok/src/main/resources/patterns).

The pattern you want is in [this file](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/libs/grok/src/main/resources/patterns/linux-syslog).

```
SYSLOG5424PRI <%{NONNEGINT:syslog5424_pri}>
```

It will match any non negative integer between a `<` and a `>`.